# How does one select the server name in a sys objects query

Tags: t-sql, inner-join, cross-join, sysobjects, sysdatabases

In T-SQL, I am trying to do something like :-

```
select * from [server_name].dbo.sys.objects
```

but I keep getting the error 'Invalid object name..'

I ultimately want to compare all the databases of the two servers
(something like the following..):--

```
Select * from [server1].dbo.Sys.Databases d1
cross join [server2].dbo.Sys.Databases d2
on d1.database_id = d2.database_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linked servers to select data from databases on two different servers within a single query.

You can set up linked servers through SQL Server Mangement Studio under Server Objects --> Linked Servers. Once you have linked [server1] to [server2] you should be able to execute your query.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
select from [server_name].[base_name].sys.objects
```

Comment: what would be the `[base_name]` ? using `dbo` gives me the above `'invalid object name..'` error

Comment: Base name is the name of the base you want to use on the other server.

Comment: umm, but what is it if not dbo ? How do I find it out ?

Comment: @heyNow He means database name.  SQL Server uses a standard 4 part identifier: `server.database.schema.object`.

Comment: ok, I cant even select from it `Select * from [server1].sysobjects` also gives error, any suggestions ?